# why can't I create a fucnction from a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, calling-convention

In React I am trying to call a certain useState based on the key I provide the function with the value as a parameter. This code throws me this error: Invalid key: bullets setBullets although I have defined setBullets earlier in the code. What is the problem

```
 const setGameState = (key, value) => {
    const setterFunctionName = `set${key.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${key.slice(1)}`;
    const setterFunction = window[setterFunctionName];
    
    if (typeof setterFunction !== 'function') {
      console.warn(`Invalid key: ${key}`, setterFunctionName);
      return;
    }
    
    setterFunction(prevValue => prevValue + value);
  };
```

I also tried this version with no luck

```
const setGameState = (key, value) => {
  const capitalizedKey = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
  const setterFunctionName = `set${capitalizedKey}`;
  
  if (typeof window[setterFunctionName] !== 'function') {
    console.warn(`Invalid key: ${key}`);
    return;
  }
  
  window[setterFunctionName](prevValue => prevValue + value);
};
```

Comment: Where are you creating functions on *the window object* and, more importantly... *why*?  It's not really clear what specifically you're asking or trying to accomplish.

Comment: You seem very lost.  Try reading the [useState docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) and following examples there.

Comment: Accessing variables through `window` won't work if they're scoped or declared with `let`/`const`. You need a different approach, but the solution will depend on what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Function names are holding a reference to a defined function somewhere in the memory stack.

Try storing those references in an object and then use the object keys to access the function references.

```
const [ bullets, setBullets ] = useState('')
const [ color, setColor ] = useState('')
const [ position, setPosition ] = useState('')

// An object to store functions
const setters = {
  bullets: setBullets,
  color: setColor,
  position: setPosition,
}

const setGameState = (key, value) => {
  
  if (typeof(setters[key]) !== 'function') {
    console.warn(`Invalid key: ${key}`, typeof(setters[key]));
    return;
  }
  
  setters[key](prevValue => prevValue + value);
};
```